# If 100% DIV is narrower than 300 px, than no float

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/w5aref0L/ (*please resize the window to better understand what is my code doing*)

```
<div class="left">
<div class="first">a a a</div>
<div class="second"><p>a a a</p></div>
</div>

.left{ width: auto; padding-left: 300px; overflow: auto; }
.first{ width: 300px; margin-left: -300px; background: red; float: left; }
.second{ width: 100%; min-width: 50%; background: blue; float: right; }
```

**What I want to achieve:** If blue DIV is narrower than 300 px, than I want him to jump under red DIV. Not float next to him.

- I tried to set him min-width, but it doesn't work.
- I don't want to use javascript
- I don't want to use @media

Comment: Why don't you want to use media or js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve exactly, the solution is to use `width:calc(100% - 300px)` for the second div, rather than `100%`, and to float it to the left.

```css
.first {width:300px; background:red; float:left;}
.second {width:calc(100% - 300px); min-width:300px; background:blue; float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="left">
<div class="first">a a a</div>
<div class="second"><p>a a a</p></div>
</div>
```

I also took the liberty of removing the negative margins, since that looked like it was a left-over from some failed attempts at getting it to work.

If this is not what you want, let me know and we can work something out!

Edit: you say you don't want to use @media, but in case you change your mind, here's a solution that uses it.

```css
.first {width:300px; background:red;}
.second {width:300px; background:blue;}
.second p {margin:0; padding:1em 0;}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .first {float:left;}
  .second {margin-left:300px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
<div class="first">a a a</div>
<div class="second"><p>a a a</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to Google calc() is supported by browsers of 80% of visitors. Is it really good practice to use it?

Comment: If you're worried about that, that could be a problem, yes. Then why not use a media query? According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=%40media), media queries are much more widely supported. (It says 83% for calc and 97% for media queries.)

Comment: @user3222169 I added another solution that does use `@media`, just in case.

Comment: I already tried code with calc(). And it's working just fine. But now I'm really thinking about using @media instead. Thank you for both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

try this

add this css:

```
.div{ height: 100px; display:inline-block;font-size:16px;}
.first{background-color: red; width: 300px; max-width:300px;}
.second{background-color: blue; width:300px;max-width:300px;}
```

add html:

```
<div class="first">a a a</div>
<div class="second">a a a</div>
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek2290/9kawkujf/

Comment: But in your code blue DIV doesn't have 100% width = is not filling remaining width of window.